# AppBarButtons ignored (once) when the on screen keyboard is visible

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

When the on-screen keyboard is visible (on Windows Mobile) and an `AppBarButton` is pressed, the keyboard disappears, but the click event is not honored. The button needs to be clicked again to raise the event. How can I make it accept the button immediately?

Comment: I would assume this to be standard behavior that Microsoft won't let you change because it would make an awkward user experience if you "just wanted to click away the keyboard" by tapping somewhere and then have to be careful not to tap the wrong stuff...

Comment: If I remember right the default `ClickMode` is `Release` so you might try adding `ClickMode="Press"` to your buttons for the desired result.

Comment: Cool, who doesn't love a good shot in the dark lol.